# Why Anaconda modules list is not exhaustive?

Tags: python, anaconda, conda

Why the list of package of Anaconda `conda list` doesn't show me all packages that I can display with `Python>>> help(modules)`

Comment: You might have installed packages outside `conda` (pip, from source...etc) which then won't be detected by conda

Comment: @Adonis if he is inside a conda environment, `conda list` will show `pip` installed modules unless you use the `--no-pip` flag.

Comment: even when I did `pip list` I got the same packages names as `conda list `

Comment: Can you give an example of which packages are being ignored?

Comment: @chrisz Thus the "from source ...etc", also if pip was installed "outside" of conda ... Just listing possibilities as there are not a lot of informations here

Comment: @chrisz I have  `locale` and `functools` for example

Comment: @hisi, ah, those are not installed packages via conda or pip, those are part of the standard library and will not be listed.

Comment: @chrisz where should I find this standard library?

Comment: https://docs.python.org/3/library/

Comment: @chrisz Is that question deserve a downvote?

Comment: @chrisz standard library is the same for python 2 and 3